# Getting error when try to list all users on the hosts

Tags: bash, automation, ansible

I am trying to get all the users I created on the hosts machine. When I run the following command on terminal, I get all the users on the machine.

```
sudo getent passwd {1000..6000} | cut -d":" -f1
```

However when I try to run it using ansible, I get an error. I tried all like enquoting in double quotes, escaping the brackets, piping the output to cat etc but nothing is working.

```yaml
---
- name: "run commands"
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: list all users
      shell: getent passwd {1000..6000} | cut -d":" -f1
      register: getent

    - debug: var=getent.stdout_lines
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, per default, Ansible is using `/bin/sh`, as pointed in the [synopsis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#synopsis) of the command.

> It is almost exactly like the [ansible.builtin.command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module) module but runs the command through a shell (`/bin/sh`) on the remote node.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#synopsis*</sup>

But `sh` won't interpret a sequence construct like `{0..10}`.

There are two ways you can overcome this:

1. Using `seq` rather:

   ```yaml
   - shell: getent passwd $(seq 1000 6000) | cut -d":" -f1
     register: getent
   ```
2. Specifying to the `shell` task that you want it executed via `bash`:

   ```yaml
   - shell: getent passwd {1000..6000} | cut -d":" -f1
     register: getent
     args:
       executable: /bin/bash
   ```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, picked the second one :) but great to know the first opton too.